# How to integrate feature of finding people in particular radius set by user?

Tags: android, google-geolocation

I am building a app which requires getting all nearby or neighboring people to the user at instant(Current active user with their current location) to be sorted distance wise and displayed in an fragment. 
Suggest algorithm, API and tutorial for the same to be followed for development.

I know geolocation API, but how it can be applied for the same. We can get coordinated of user and all active users but I am unable integrate logic that storing all in database then applying sorting I think is a slow process and difficult.

Answer (score 0):

---

Since it is an android app what you would have is user's last known location which you can listen for every time users open the app.

This data (latitude and longitude) can be sent to your server and then be used to find users with the radius

Comment: I am aware that we can get the coordinates of the user using geolocation API. How can we implement finding other users within radius, I need some reference to documentation or tutorial.